# How can select two types and count id monthly wise using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table. I need to fetch result and show in line graph. I need result of count(id) and type monthly wise. I have tried a query but not working. In graph I need to show two type(booking and membership). Is it possible to get two types and count monthly wise in a single query?

**SQL Query**

```
 SELECT COUNT(id), type, MONTHNAME(created_at) FROM orders WHERE YEAR(created_at) = 2016 ORDER BY created_at GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
```

**orders table**

```
 id     type        created_at  
  1     booking     2016-01-12
  2     membership  2016-01-12
  3     booking     2016-05-11
  4     booking     2016-05-15
  5     booking     2016-07-07
  6     membership  2016-07-08
  7     membership  2016-07-09
  8     membership  2016-08-16
  9     booking     2016-08-17
  10    membership  2016-08-19
```

**Expecting output is :**
eg: In this case (2016-07-07) I need count is 3 and type is "booking, membership, membership"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(created_at),
       SUM(type = 'Booking') as Booking,
       SUM(type = 'Membership') as Membership
FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(created_at) = 2016 
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
ORDER BY MIN(created_at );
```

Notes:

- I usually put the `GROUP BY` columns first in an aggregation query and the calculated columns after them.  (Personal preference).
- MySQL treats a boolean expression as "1" for true and "0" for false, so the `SUM()` is counting the number of true values.  In most other databases, you need to use a `CASE` expression.
- The `ORDER BY` goes after the `GROUP BY`.
- When creating aggregation queries, don't learn bad habits.  Hence, I put an aggregation function around `CREATED_AT`, because columns not in the `GROUP BY` should never be "bare".

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this.

`GROUP_CONCAT()` - function returns a string with concatenated non-NULL value from a group.

So your query should be like:

```
SELECT count(id) as total, GROUP_CONCAT(type) as Types, MONTHNAME(created_at) as MONTH
from orders group by MONTH(created_at)
```